# IOS App Indexing Implementation on Google SERP

Tags: google-app-indexing

I have a website and an IOS app; I want the app to surface on Google SERP, on IOS mobile devices.

I searched for ways to implement app indexing; I read this guide on the Apple development site. I understood how to do a website to an app association and implement universal links in the app. What I didn't manage to figure out is: How do you surface the IOS app "install" button on Google SERP that will lead to the Apple app store page of the app.

It is essential to mention that I only want the "install button" to appear for homepage searches of the website.

I would appreciate any help you can give me.

[App store install button on Google search results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iQGRm.png)

I want to know how to make the above scenario happen